# Google checkout integration in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there any way to integrate Google Checkout in iphone.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [is it possible to intigrate google checkout with iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521603/is-it-possible-to-intigrate-google-checkout-with-iphone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Technically.

Run it in a UIWebView would be the simplest way of doing it.

You could also make custom calls to the Google Checkout with [NSUrlConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)

Just make sure you do not interfere with the Apple approval guidelines. If you want to charge inapp purchases, you will have to use iTunes. Apple will not let go of their 30% ;]

Same goes for paypal integration.

Comment: i guess you are right. its possible in UIWebView. is there any sample application available which tells how to use it. if yes please tell me.

Comment: If i am using UIWebView where should i pass the amount.?.Can you give some more information.??